# Ngnix default all ports to port 80

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I had an old server setup where I have given people the url to a service with the port 420, example.corp.com:420, now I moved all services to the regular 80 port in Ngnix and I want all requests coming from example.corp.com:420 to default back to example.corp.com instead. Is there a way to tell Ngnix to go to app1 regardless of the port number given? I tried few things but none worked. Here is my current configuration. Thanks in advance.

```
upstream unicorn-app1 {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app1.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.corp.com;
  root /home/example/apps/wm/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn-app1;
      break;
    }
  }
}

upstream unicorn-app2{
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app2.sock;
}

server {
  listen 420;
  server_name example.corp.com;
  root /home/example/apps/app2/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn-app2;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually a better way is to make port 420 to redirect to port 80, so that people will slowly stop using port 480, just use a 301 redirect

```
server {
    listen 480;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it to work. I think it's fairly simple when you understand what's going on, I just missed a small detail that was necessary for the whole thing to work. So whenever you need to have different ports of an Ngnix server default back to a specific port, all you have to do is to define the other ports apps to point to the 80 port app. Here is the solution, I put in bold what had to be changed to make it work. Hope it helps.

```
upstream unicorn-app1 {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app1.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.corp.com;
  root /home/example/apps/wm/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn-app1;
      break;
    }
  }
}

upstream unicorn-app2{
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.**app1**.sock;
}

server {
  listen 420;
  server_name example.corp.com;
  root /home/example/apps/**app1**/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn-**app1**;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```